# Html input text can't be edited

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                   <title>OrderForm</title>
        <style>
            header{
                background-color:brown;
                color:cadetblue;
                text-align:center;
                height:100px;
                width:100%;
                border: none;
            }
            section {
                height: 800px;
                width: 100%;
                overflow: hidden;
                zoom: 1;
                border: none;
            }
            footer {
                background-color: brown;
                color: cadetblue;
                text-align: center;
                height: 50px;
                width: 100%;
                border: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body >


        <a href="User.html" style="position:absolute;right:20px;left:20px;background-color:white;color:black">Back</a>
        <header>

            <img id="Logo" src="images/mylogo.jpg" style="height: 75px; width: 75px; float: left;padding:15px 15px;" />
            <h1 style="padding:25px;font-size:45px;">Our Express Name</h1>
        </header>
        <section>

            <span>
                <b style="font-size:35px;padding:60px;">
                    Receiver's Information:
                </b>
            </span>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <span style="padding:180px;">
                Receiver's Name: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="text" id="receiverName" style="font-size:20px;height:25px;"  ></input>

            </span>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <span style="padding: 180px;">
                Receiver's Tel:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="text" id="receiverTel" style="font-size:20px;height:25px;"/>
            </span>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <span style="padding: 180px;">
                To:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                Province&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                City&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                Street
                <br />
                <br />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <select id="receiverProvince">
                    <option value="null">Select</option>
                    <option value="ShanDong">ShanDong</option>
                </select>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <select id="receiverCity">
                    <option value="null">Select</option>
                    <option value="QingDao">QingDao</option>
                </select>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <select id="receiverStreet" onchange=getreceive()>
                    <option value="null">Select</option>
                    <option value="1">ShiNan</option>
                    <option value="2">LaoShan</option>
                    <option value="3">LiCang</option>
                    <option value="4">HuangDao</option>
                    <option value="5">ChengYang</option>

                </select>
                <br />
                <br />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                DetailedAddress:
                <br />
                <br />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <textarea id="receiverAddress" style="height:200px;width:250px;font-size:20px;text-align:center">
                    Please write down your receiver's address.
                </textarea>
                <br />
            </span>
            <br />
            <br />
            <span style="padding: 180px;">
                Time for courier to come:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <textarea id="comingTime" style="font-size:20px;height:25px;"></textarea>
            </span>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <span style="padding: 180px;">
                <button type="button" onclick=finish() style="text-align:center;font-size:20px;border:6px dashed Tomato;background-color:lightskyblue;color:teal;border-radius:15px;height:80px;width:180px;float:right">
                    A &nbsp;&nbsp;f &nbsp;&nbsp;f &nbsp;&nbsp;i &nbsp;&nbsp;r &nbsp;&nbsp;m
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div id="Sender" style="background-color: whitesmoke; height: 100%; width: 50%; float: left; ">
            <span>
                <b style="font-size:35px;padding:60px;">
                    Sender's Information:
                </b>
            </span>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <span style="padding:180px;">
                Sender's Name: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <textarea id="senderName" style="font-size:20px;height:25px;"></textarea>
            </span>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <span style="padding: 180px;">
                Sender's Tel:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <textarea id="senderTel" style="font-size:20px;height:25px;"></textarea>
            </span>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <span style="padding: 180px;">
                From:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                Province&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                City&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                Street
                <br />
                <br />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <select id="senderProvince">
                    <option value="null">Select</option>
                    <option value="ShanDong">ShanDong</option>
                </select>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <select id="senderCity">
                    <option value="null">Select</option>
                    <option value="QingDao">QingDao</option>
                </select>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <select id="senderStreet" onchange="getsend()">
                    <option value="null">Select</option>
                    <option value="1">ShiNan</option>
                    <option value="2">LaoShan</option>
                    <option value="3">LiCang</option>
                    <option value="4">HuangDao</option>
                    <option value="5">ChengYang</option>
                </select>
                <br />
                <br />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                DetailedAddress:
                <br />
                <br />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <textarea id="senderAddress" style="height:200px;width:250px;font-size:20px;text-align:center">
                    Please write down your address.
                </textarea>
                <br />
            </span>
            <br />
            <br />
            <span style="padding: 180px;">
                Good's Type:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <textarea id="goodsType" style="font-size:20px;height:25px;"></textarea>
            </span>
            <span style="padding: 180px;">
                Good's weight:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <select id="weight" style="font-size:20px;height:25px;" onchange="getweight()">
                    <option value="null">Select</option>
                    <option value="1">0~5KG</option>
                    <option value="2">5~10KG</option>
                    <option value="3">above 10kg</option>
                </select>
            </span>
        </div>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <h2 style="padding:10px;font-size:25px;">By our group</h2><p id="message"></p>
    </footer>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi i have met a weird problem that is the input field inside the section doesn't work. Already checked removing css , removing section tag. And if you create an input text inside header or footer then it works fine.

Textarea works fine, the problem is with input text and province dropdown select type.

Comment: According to your code there isn't an input inside of the section.

Comment: What browser are you using? I've tested this in Chrome and IE and it seems to work fine when adding your input inside of the section.

Comment: Noticed small typo `<section >` (the space)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed only the problems mentioned. I changed inline and main CSS a little bit and code. So design is also changed. I put two separate sections, one for receiver information and other for sender's information. I coded only the receiver part. The code I am attaching does not include sender part.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
               <title>OrderForm</title>
    <style>
        header{
            background-color:brown;
            color:cadetblue;
            text-align:center;
            height:100px;
            width:100%;
            border: none;
        }
        section {
            height: auto;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            zoom: 1;
            border: none;
        }
        footer {
            background-color: brown;
            color: cadetblue;
            text-align: center;
            height: 50px;
            width: 100%;
            border: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

Back
        
                
                Our Express Name
        
        
        
            Receiver's Information:  
            
               Receiver's Name:

```
        <span style="margin-left:10px;">
            Receiver's Tel:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="text" id="receiverTel" style="font-size:20px;height:25px;"/>
        </span>
        </div>

        <br>
        <br>

        <div id="2" style="padding: 30px;">
            To:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            Province&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <select id="receiverProvince">
                <option value="null">Select</option>
                <option value="ShanDong">ShanDong</option>
            </select>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            City&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <select id="receiverCity">
                <option value="null">Select</option>
                <option value="QingDao">QingDao</option>
            </select>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            Street &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

            <select id="receiverStreet" onchange=getreceive()>
                <option value="null">Select</option>
                <option value="1">ShiNan</option>
                <option value="2">LaoShan</option>
                <option value="3">LiCang</option>
                <option value="4">HuangDao</option>
                <option value="5">ChengYang</option>

            </select>
            </div>

            <br>
            <br>

            <div id="3">
            Detailed Address:
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <textarea id="receiverAddress" style="height:100px;width:250px;font-size:20px;text-align:center">
                Please write down your receiver's address.
            </textarea>
            </div>

            <br />
            <br />

           <div>
          Time for courier to come:
           <textarea id="comingTime" style="font-size:20px;height:25px;"></textarea>
           </div>

       </section>

     <section>  
     </section>
<footer>
    <h2 style="padding:10px;font-size:25px;">By our group</h2><p id="message"></p>

</footer>
```